# \vspace in examdesign package

Tags: examdesign, vspace

I'm using examdesign package.

In my example, the first \vspace which is in examtop works, but the second \vspace outside the examtop doesn't work at all.

What might be wrong?

```
\vspace{1cm} % this works
Name: \rule{4in}{.4pt}  \quad  \noindent id:\enspace\hrulefill
\end{examtop}

\vspace{2cm} % this doesn't work
```

### Added

1. When I add \vspace{1cm} before the \end{examtop}, I can get 1cm space.
2. When I add \vspace{1cm} after the \begin{truefalse}, I can get 1cm space after the `Section1 ...' printout.
3. When I add \vspace{1cm} before the \begin{truefalse}, nothing happens.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{examdesign}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{totpages}
\usepackage[margin=0.9in]{geometry}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\usepackage{framed}

\SectionFont{\large\sffamily}
\Fullpages
\ContinuousNumbering
\DefineAnswerWrapper{}{}
\NumberOfVersions{1}

\ShortKey       % shows a short key answer sheet
%\NoKey         % Print key ?

\NoRearrange    % Random arrange with latex? (leave it UNCOMMENTED, R will do all of the dirty work)

\newcommand{\myversion}{} % this line is very important as it locates and allows the printed test to show the number of  the test (DONT DELETE IT)

\newcommand{\ClassName}{CSC 260-001:Quiz 1 - Feb 1, 2018}

\begin{document}

\begin{examtop}

% detais of the exam (you should probably edit this!)
\begin{center}
    \textbf{\Large \ClassName} \\
 \end{center}

\vspace{1cm} % this works
Name: \rule{4in}{.4pt}  \quad  \noindent id:\enspace\hrulefill
\end{examtop}

\vspace{2cm} % this doesn't work
\begin{truefalse}[title={True/False (2 points each, total 20 points)},
                  resetcounter=yes] %,suppressprefix]
\textbf{\large Write ``T'' if the statement is true and ``F'' otherwise.}

\begin{question}
  \answer{True} This sentence is not false.
\end{question}

\begin{question}
  \answer{T} `Roger \& Me' chronicles one man's attempt to get into
  Disneyland so that he can visit Toontown.
\end{question}  
\end{truefalse}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that `examtop` behaves like a float. Why don’t you place the `\vspace` before `\end{examtop}`?

Comment: @Jasper, it works, but this doesn't seem to solve my problem. I'll update my question.

Comment: \vspace delays until the end of the line (vmode) before performing a \vskip.  \vspace does nothing at the top or bottom of a page or minipage.  For that you need \vspace*.

Comment: @JohnKormylo  I also tried `\vspace*` but this will put the space before the `examtop` environment resulting in an additional empty page before the actual output.